# Aerodynamics Question: Calculating force and moments of a surface using C_p at various points.

Tags: 3d, surface-integrals

I have been given a data that contains x, y, z coordinates; coefficient of pressure and the coefficient of friction at different points. So far, I tried calculating the force coefficients and moment coefficients for each points [see attachment 1].

Now, in order to get the total force, I have been told to find the surface integral and I have no idea how to do that since I don't have any equations to apply surface integral.

I was wondering if I should be calculating the areas of each sections and multiply the calculated coefficients to them, and then sum them up?

Help would be greatly appreciated.

[attachment 1: first part of my calculations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NENOK.png)

Comment: So far what you have shown seem to be completely generic equations -- the same equations could describe any object of any size and shape subjected to any airflow. (Very strange to see angle brackets around an entire equation, though.) For the integral you would need to know what the surface is, and specifically how to calculate the forces at any point on the surface.

Comment: Hello David! I am trying to use this formula to calculate the forces exerted on an elevon using the pressure coefficients and friction coefficients at multiple x,y,z coordinates within the elevon. 
I copied them directly from the chat my colleague sent for the equations (you may ignore them)
I am thinking of making small surfaces, finding their area and calculating the force exerted on each surfaces, and then sum them up. But I am not sure if that would be the right way to do this.

Comment: I think that's actually how it's usually done. The formulas are fine, you'll just need to figure out the numbers that go into them.

Comment: Thanks so much! I really appreciate it!

Comment: One small question!
Since I have different Cp values for all 3 points, do I use the average of the three Cp's to calculate the force coefficients?